# How to put !important in all CSS properties using SASS or CSS3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, sass

I'm using the property of BootStrap **@include ipad** along with SASS to various styles define power to the Ipad.

What I wonder is if there is a way for me to create some variable or something more advanced for all properties within any class *(or anything else)* are with! Important?

Example:

```
p {
   white-space: normal;
   height: auto;
    @include ipad {
     width: 280px !important;
     overflow: hidden !important;
     text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
     white-space: nowrap !important;
     }
}
```

Its place automatically **!important** in all the properties when the CSS is compiled by SASS?

Thank!

Comment: If you're using `!important` that much, you should probably rethink how your selectors are specified.

Comment: yes I know, but I wonder if there is a way to do this!

Answer (score 2):

No.  Sass does not have a programmatic way of applying the `!important` flag to the rules for any given selector.

The only thing you *can* do is increase the specificity of the selector in question.

```
p {
   white-space: normal;
   height: auto;
   @include ipad {
        body & {
            width: 280px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    }
}
```